# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" In reactjs app

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I keep getting this error. It worked previously, but over time it started giving me the error.

I tried changing the arrow function into a standard function. I also tried using the same code in a different app, and that worked. But for some reason I only get the error in this app.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import NewSingle from './NewSingle';
import Error from './Error';

class News extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      news: [],
      error: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/${this.props.news.type}?${this.props.news.query}&apiKey=ae3aff618e7d4b71b666bd9d0b10f053`;

    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          news: data.articles
        })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({
          error: true
        })
      });
  }

  renderItems() {
    if (!this.state.error) {
      return this.state.news.map((item) => (
        <NewSingle key={item.url} item={item} />
      ));
    } else {
      return <Error />
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        {this.renderItems()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default News;
```

```
import React from 'react';

const NewSingle = ({item}) => (
    <div className='col s4'>
        <div className='card'>
            <div className='card-image'>
                <img src={item.urlToImage} alt={item.title} />
                <span className='card-title'>{item.source.name}</span>
            </div>
            <div className='card-content'>
            <p>{item.title}</p>
            </div>
            <div className='card-action'>
                <a href={item.url} target='_blank' rel="noopener noreferrer">Full article</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
);

export default NewSingle;
```

The api is supposed to render news data from the api.

Comment: your api key is visible in this post, not sure if that was intended

Comment: It wasn't, but it's fine, I regenerated a new one.

Comment: Seems like `render()` is getting called before your `fetch` chain is finishing. maybe use a `debugger` before `return this.state.news.map(...)` to see what your dealing with

Comment: Either state or news is undefined during that render call. Log them to find out which.

The fact that it's only happening sometimes means it's probably an issue with asynchronicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `fetch` works the way you are expecting. Even on a bad request it will not throw an error, meaning `data.articles` will sometimes be undefined. `fetch` sets `response.ok` depending on if it was successful, so you can use that to check before proceeding.

Try changing your fetch to something like this:

```
fetch(url)
  .then((response) => {
    // Add this check and throw an error if it fails
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error(response.statusText);
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    this.setState({
      news: data.articles
    })
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    this.setState({
      error: true
    })
  });
```

Another thing to point out, newsapi.org requires `q=query` so make sure `this.props.news.query` includes `q=...`, or add it before like:
`https://newsapi.org/v2/${this.props.news.type}?q=${this.props.news.query}`

Comment: Thank you, this seemed to fix the issue!

Answer (score 2):

Try protecting the code by

```
if (!this.state.error) {
      return this.state.news.length> 0 && this.state.news.map((item) => (
        <NewSingle key={item.url} item={item} />
      ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `error` only gets set after the fetch and you're not checking for whether `news` actually holds data, you should add a conditional either before `return` in your render, or change the conditional in renderItems to `if (!this.state.error && (this.state.news && this.state.news.length))`.